# iTMSTransporter is available on the early-access update channel

Tags: macos, itmstransporter

I'm running into 2 issues that I'm not sure how to solve regarding validating apps to publish to the Mac App Store.

[image]

> A new Version of iTMStransporter is available on the early-access update channel. Specify '-updateChannel earlyAccess' on the command line to test it out.
>
> ---Irrelavant issue about sandbox---
>
> Your version of iTMSTransporter will be updated in approximately in 2 days.

I have looked into the App Store and I have not found anything that seems relevant. Executing that command returns `command not found: -updateChannel`

Comment: Having the exact same issue here. I am building my app via Expo and is preparing to upload the iOS build to App Store Connect.

Comment: @Kong I managed to solve my issue. See the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved my problem:

1. Open terminal
2. navigate to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/Current/itms/bin`
3. Fill in `./iTMSTransporter -updateChannel earlyAccess` in the cmd
4. Use transporter

Comment: For those who are getting error `no such file or directory: ./iTMSTransporter` when in Step 3, change the command to `./bin/iTMSTransporter -updateChannel earlyAccess`

Comment: Thanks, the answer is updated to reflect this change. :)